# Save RSS in the internal storage

Tags: android

i would like to store the RSS-feed I'm getting from a site in the internal storage,in order to be visible when the device WiFi is disabled.

I have never used internal storage before but I found in the internet that this is the best way to store the RSS-feed for offline view.

Do you have any way on mind to do that?thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)...